# Get the most recent date from the mysql using knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

```
"SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM stocks) AND industry = 'Health Care'"
```

Above is the query that I used before but now I need to change it into knex form. I'm ok with others but can't figure out how to change the where condition to knex form.

There are like thousands of date for each of the stocks, and I want to get only the most date from it. There are hips of examples for simple query but none for the knex form.

Answer (score 0):

Would you know how to rewrite this one?

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM stocks s
  JOIN (SELECT max(timestamp) ts FROM stocks) x 
    ON x.ts = s.timestamp
 WHERE s.industry = 'Health Care'
```

Comment: Not sure...  Does it do the same job as mine?

Comment: Yes, and (if appropriately indexed) more efficiently

Comment: .join(db.select(max(timestamp)).from stocks)
.on()... not sure how it works

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/api/stock", function (req, res, next) {
  req.db
    .from("stocks")
    .select("*")
    .where("name", "=","Agilent Technologies Inc" )
    .then((rows) => {
      res.json({ Error: false, Message: "Success", City: rows })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      res.json({ Error: false, Message: "Error in MySQL query" })
    })
})
```

This is what I have came up with so far, this prints out like 100 of rows. Since I haven't put any conditions... But not sure where to get started

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM stocks s
  JOIN (SELECT max(timestamp) ts FROM stocks) x 
    ON x.ts = s.timestamp
 WHERE s.industry = 'Health Care'
```

is

```
knex({s: 'stocks'})
  .select('s.*')
  .join(
    knex('stocks').select(knex.raw('max(??) as ts', ['timestamp'])).as('x'),
    'x.ts', 
    '=', 
    's.timestamp'
  ).where('s.industry', 'Health Care');
```

runkit: https://runkit.com/embed/s0iibv1byrd0